# Using Egit or GitExtension to view multiple commits at once

Tags: git, eclipse, egit, git-extensions

Hey this might be a weird question but I am reviewing commits from another developer and I was wondering if there is any way to somehow view all of their commits together in one and kind of "squash" them together but not actually by squashing. What I am trying to do is view all of their changes at once and have any of the changes made in earlier commits that might have been undone or further changed in later commits taken out. That way I can basically just view the "final product" from all of their commits.

Does anyone know if this is possible using either Eclipses git or GitExtension, or even something like git bash. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In  GitExtensions, if all the commits you want to review are together, you could select the one before the first and (with 'ctrl' key) the last one.

It will do a diff between these 2 commits.